# SwiftUI TabView bottom whitespace (PageTabViewStyle)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I am trying to make an app that has pages (kind of like how a book app displays the pages of a book). To do this I am using the TabView with the PageTabViewStyle modifier. The issue is that I want the tab's content (which is in a scrollView if that makes a difference) to go all the way down the screen. At first I thought "oh that's easy i'll just turn off the safe area" but the whitespace remains. I've tried every which way of disabling the safe area. It worked once when I turned off the safe area on the parent view but the second I swiped it threw an error and went back to normal.  I think it has something to do with the tab bar at the bottom but I'm not sure.

I've tried turning off the safe area, and I dissected the problem and it starts happening only once the tab view is added. I saw some fourms that were saying it's a bug but I don't really know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I figured it out, it was just a matter of putting the .ignoresSafeArea on the right view. Although it is a bit glitchy and throws a minor error, it achieves the intended goal and I’ll focus on ironing out the kinks later